# Getting API to work in JSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, twilio, jsx

My code below is from my container, but if I pull out just the Twilio API and place it in a seperate .js file, it works when I execute it in on the CLI using node, but not in my JSX file. I need it to execute on the click of a button, within my getTime method, but each time I attempt to build my app with webpack after incorporating the twilio module, I receive errors stating "cannot find net", "cannot find tls" and "cannot find fs". What can I do to get around this, and incorporate the Twilio api in my code.

```
 import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
var firebase = require('firebase');
var hash = require('object-hash');

var AccountSid = "**********";
var AuthToken = "*************";
var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio.RestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

export default class App extends Component {

componentWillMount(){
        //Send an SMS text message
client.messages.create({ 
    to: "+15558675309", 
    from: '+**', 
    body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?", 
    mediaUrl: "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg",  
});
    }
    getTime(){
        var localTime = new Date();
        var bob = {first: 'Bob', last: 'Samuels', time: localTime };
        var convert = localTime.toLocaleString();
        alert(hash(bob));
        alert(convert);
    }
    render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>YES !</h1>
      <button onClick ={ this.getTime }>Clock In</button>
      <button onClick ={ this.getTime }>Clock Out</button>
    </div>
  );
 }
```

Comment: Presumably you're getting those errors because you're trying to load a server side library on the client. you might need a server side proxy (node server) that your client side app calls

Comment: So I should make a route to handle the request ? Right now I have react-router handling all my routing @azium

Comment: yeah so react-router is a client side library (runs on users browser). you may need to create a proxy server (node/express) that calls twilio, then you call your express endpoint from the browser

Comment: Thanks ! Can you possibily give me an example of this? If you list it as a answer, I'll be sure to accept it. @azium

Comment: the express docs are decent. http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html and scotch.io has good tutorials and creating servers with node https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Comment: I'm confused. I already have a express/node server going in my app. Im running node on IIS, which routes to my express/node instance, and that then gets routed to my react-router for the routes. So would I just put the endpoint in my current express/node implementation? @azium

Comment: Current setup: https://github.com/MSULibraries/IISNode/blob/master/public/website1/server.js

Comment: yeah totally, just expose a different endpoint like `/api/createMessage` that handles twillio logic, and hit that endpoint from react

Comment: Gotcha, thanks a lot ! @azium

Answer (score 0):

From @azium:

> you're getting those errors because you're trying to load a server
>   side library on the client. you might need a server side proxy (node
>   server) that your client side app calls
>
> just expose a different endpoint like `/api/createMessage` that handles
>   twilio [logic](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node), and hit that endpoint from react